# How to generate a lot of QR Code Images, that represent random unique numbers (not url) in Java?

Tags: java, qr-code

I am trying to generate a 100 of QR Code Images, that represent random numbers like "1321434354".

I made a class to generate my random numbers, but I don`t know how to generate more than one QR Code Image.

```
public class Numbers {


    public static double[] anArray;

    public static double[] list() {
        anArray = new double[10];
        for(int i=0;i<anArray.length;i++)
        {
            anArray[i] = randomFill();
        }
        return anArray;
    }

    public static void print(){
        for(double n: anArray){
            System.out.println(n+" ");
        }
    }


    public static double randomFill(){

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt();
        return randomNum;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        list();
        print();

    }


}
```

I guess i should generate more images too ??

```
public class Create_QR {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            **String qrCodeData = Arrays.toString(Numbers.anArray);
            System.out.println("Afiseaza: " + qrCodeData);**
            String filePath = "F:\\QR_CODE\\image3.png";
            String charset = "UTF-8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
            Map < EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel > hintMap = new HashMap < EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel > ();
            hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
            BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
                    new String(qrCodeData.getBytes(charset), charset),
                    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200, hintMap);
            MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1), new File(filePath));
            System.out.println("QR Code image created successfully!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you need to create a new image (hence, new filePath) for every new QR code?

Comment: In addition to @CInvt : to run some action multiple times you should use loop (`for` or `while` or `do while`), but I can't see looping in your code

Comment: I don`t know how to do a loop to generate a new image every time..for the random number..